# Matlab Dissecting Extracting Camera Projection Matrix to position and rotation

Tags: matlab, matrix, camera, projection, calibration

I have 6 points in space with known coordinates in mm and corresponding 2D pixel coordinates in the image (image size is 640x320 pixels and points coordinates have been measured from upper left of the image. also I have the focal length of the camera as 43.456mm. trying to find the camera position and orientation.
My matlab code here will give me the camera location as -572.8052
 -676.7060 548.7718 and seems correct but I am having a hard time finding the orientation values (yaw pitch roll of the camera in degrees)
I know that the rotation values should be 60.3,5.6,-45.1 
the last 4 lines in my code needs to be updated to output the orientation of the camera.
I would really really appreciate your help on this.
Thanks.

Here is my matlab code:

```
Points_2D= [135 183 ; 188 129 ; 298 256 ; 301 43 ; 497  245; 464 110];

Points_3D= [-22.987 417.601 -126.543 ; -132.474 37.67 140.702 ; ...
            388.445 518.635 -574.784 ; 250.015 259.803 67.137 ; ...
            405.915 -25.566 -311.834 ; 568.859 164.809 -162.604  ];


M = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 

A = []; 
for i = 1:size(Points_2D,1) 
    u_i = Points_2D(i,1); 
    v_i = Points_2D(i,2); 
    x_i = Points_3D(i,1); 
    y_i = Points_3D(i,2); 
    z_i = Points_3D(i,3); 
    A_vec_1 = [x_i y_i z_i 1 0 0 0 0 -u_i*x_i -u_i*y_i -u_i*z_i -u_i]; %
    A_vec_2 = [ 0 0 0 0 x_i y_i z_i 1 -v_i*x_i -v_i*y_i -v_i*z_i -v_i]; %
    A(end+1,:) = A_vec_1;
    A(end+1,:) = A_vec_2;
end 

[U,S,V] = svd(A);
M = V(:,end);
M = transpose(reshape(M,[],3));

Q = M(:,1:3); 
m_4 = M(:,4); 
Center = (-Q^-1)*m_4


k=[43.456/640 0 320 ;0 43.456/320 160;0 0 1 ];
Rotation= (Q^-1)*k;
CC=Rotation'
eul=rotm2eul(CC)
```

Comment: Do you still need help on this? Or was it a homework/project that you are done?

Comment: No I am still looking for a solution and it's been years since I am out of school! can you help?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to find? rotation and translation of the camera with respect to a position, i.e. (0,0) of camera center?

Comment: I have 0,0,0 as origin in the world also 3d coordinates of 6 points in space (x,y,z) There is a camera in the scene that took a photo of this 6 points and so I have 2d coordinates (x,y) of those points in the photo. I am trying to find position and orientation of the camera which took the photo.My code finds the position which seems fine but I need to find orientation (yaw,pitch,roll) of the camera in degrees. everybody says it's so easy to do but never found a solution. I also know the focal length of the camera to be 43.456mm if that's needed..

Comment: I will pay $100 thru paypal if you or the first person who can write a matlab code to find position and orientation of the camera based on these known information and I am not joking.

Comment: Haha, I don't need money, and I'm not here for money but if you really want to pay me, help poor people instead or some orphans etc.

Comment: sure I will donate to childfoundation. Thanks,

Comment: I added my code, hope it will help.

Comment: can't wait to try the code. Thanks again I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: 6 points are enough but it is likely that you have some error. To get a better performance, it is recommended to have more than 6 points, like 10-15 preferably.

Your code seems correct until:

```
Q = M(:,1:3); 
m_4 = M(:,4);
```

So you are looking for extrinsic and intrinsic parameters of the camera, i.e. `rotation`, `translation`, `alpha`(skew in x direction), `ro`, `beta`(skew in x direction), `u0`, `v0` (translation of camera center). So a total of 5 intrinsics, 6 extrinsic parameters.

Here is a [link](http://engineering.nyu.edu/~gerig/CS-GY-6643-S2017/Materials/Slides-Camera-Calibration-Abdallah.pdf) which explains the details how to calculate those parameters. I had a code which I didn't test thoroughly, may be some errors but it was working in my case.

Continuing from `M` which is the 3x4 matrix you found:

```
a1 = M(1, 1:3);
a2 = M(2, 1:3);
a3 = M(3, 1:3);

b = M(1:3,4);

% Decomposition of the parameters
eps = 1; %this can be -1 or +1, based on the value you choose, you will have two different results.
ro = eps/sqrt(sumsqr(a3));
r3 = ro*a3;
u0 = ro.^2*(dot(a1,a3))
v0 = ro.^2*(dot(a2,a3))

cos_theta = -dot(cross(a1,a3),cross(a2,a3))/ ...
         dist_cross(a1,a3)/(dist_cross(a2,a3));
theta = acos(cos_theta);
alpha = ro^2*dist_cross(a1,a3)*sin(theta)
beta = ro^2*dist_cross(a2,a3)*sin(theta)
theta_deg = theta*180/pi
r1 = 1/dist_cross(a2,a3)*cross(a2,a3);
r2 = cross(r3,r1);
R = [r1;r2;r3] % Rotation matrix 3x3

% ro*A.inv(R) = K
K = [alpha  -alpha*cot(theta) u0;
     0      beta/sin(theta)   v0;
     0              0         1  ];
T = ro*(inv(K)*b) % Translation matrix, 1x3
```

where

```
function [dis] = dist_cross(mi,mj)
    dis = sqrt(sumsqr(cross(mi,mj)));
end
```

I don't guarantee it is totally correct but it should help.

Comment: I will test run this when I get home tonight. If it works you are my hero..

Comment: It did not work. My problem is simpler I do not have any skew or distortion parameter.,I also know the focal length which in your code not sure where it is..

Comment: What is the output, or the error? Skew and alpha, beta are intrinsic parameters. If your camera doesnt have skew, then, theta will be pi/2. Alpha is related to pixel density or the length of one pixel.

Comment: OK I am trying to get this to work, There is no skew or distortion in my image so it means alpha is pi/2 right? and how about beta? what is theta

I know the resolution of image is 640x320. does it mean I have to set u0 and v0 to 320 and 160?
Thanks again.

Comment: I expect to get rotation angles of 60.3 , 5.6, -45.1 degrees. but this code outputs a 3x3 matrix for R. i used rotm2eul(R) to get angles but they are not even close to the angles I expect.

Comment: Theta should be something very close to pi/2. Alpha is related to number of pixels x direction and beta is related to y direction. Yes, u0 v0 should be close to center

Comment: Rotation will be 3×3 matrix in this code. I dont know how you can convert to rotation in each axis